# Every derived table must have it's own duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql

There are countless of questions about this subject here on StackOverflow, but somehow I'm not grasping the concept of this error message. I have the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as `num` FROM(SELECT bedrijfsnaam FROM profiles LEFT JOIN profile_subrubriek ON profiles.ID=profile_subrubriek.profile_id LEFT JOIN rubrieken ON profile_subrubriek.subrubriek_id=rubrieken.ID WHERE rubrieken.rubriek = 'Aannemersbedrijven' UNION SELECT bedrijfsnaam FROM profiles LEFT JOIN profile_subrubriek ON profiles.ID=profile_subrubriek.profile_id LEFT JOIN rubrieken ON profile_subrubriek.subrubriek_id=rubrieken.ID WHERE profiles.hoofdrubriek = 'Aannemersbedrijven')
```

After reading some of the other answered questions, I've tried things like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as `num` FROM(SELECT bedrijfsnaam AS profielenaantal1 FROM profiles LEFT JOIN profile_subrubriek ON profiles.ID=profile_subrubriek.profile_id LEFT JOIN rubrieken ON profile_subrubriek.subrubriek_id=rubrieken.ID WHERE rubrieken.rubriek = 'Aannemersbedrijven' UNION SELECT bedrijfsnaam  AS profielenaantal2 FROM profiles LEFT JOIN profile_subrubriek ON profiles.ID=profile_subrubriek.profile_id LEFT JOIN rubrieken ON profile_subrubriek.subrubriek_id=rubrieken.ID WHERE profiles.hoofdrubriek = 'Aannemersbedrijven')
```

But no luck. What am I missing?
Thanks!

Comment: What does 'no luck' mean?

Comment: @Emmad Kareem, it meant I got the error message from my topic title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing table alias and too complex query. remove unnessearly part.
I am assuming your error message is `Every derived table must have its own alias`, (can't find `it's own duplicate`)

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) as `num` 
FROM
(
    ....
) AS tbl_alias;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That fixed it. However: I dont really understand why.. You think you could explain?

Comment: @user2704687 It's just MySQL's characteristic. ;-)